# centos8 docker image and rootfs tarball construction blocked by user interaction

Tags: centos, docker

When trying to build a centos rootfs tarball the hard way (see [centos docs](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-build/tree/master/docker)) my livemedia-creator run hangs with:

## Command

```
livemedia-creator --make-tar --iso=/root/boot8.iso \
--ks=/root/centos-8.ks --image-name=centos8-docker.tar.xz
```

## Stall point

```
Domain installation still in progress. You can reconnect to 
the console to complete the installation process.
```

- Cannot connect with virsh
- Cannot use vnc option

So, I can't make a rootfs tarball which I'd use to make a base docker image.  I let it run for a few hours, nothing of use in the logs and I gather something interactive is going on but I can't reach the console

Comment: Why can't you open the console?

Comment: I wish I knew, when I try to connect to the console it seems to connect but there's no output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centos recently released the centos8 image. It is delayed from the rest of the release by a week+ probably because they generate images once per month. Seems weird to me but it's their free OS which I'd like to use, so gratitude.

https://hub.docker.com/_/centos